# loop in data table is too slow for big data

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, data.table, bigdata

i have a problem -the loop with data.table but a little complicated.

```
VisitSources <- as.vector(DF$PVsource)


 for (i in 2:nrow(DF)) {

   if(DF[i,visitID]==DF[i-1,visitID]) {

    VisitSources[i]=VisitSources[i-1]

  }
 }
DF=cbind(DF,VisitSources)
```

It should run on 4 mln rows, so time is terrible (3hours). I tied a lot but nothing seems to help. Can anybody help? this must be data.table object.

```
sth simmilar works fine i quickly:
DF[,channel := as.character(channel)][VisitSources=="google", channel := "Organic"]
```

regards, 
dorota

Comment: Please read https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support

Answer (score 4):

Really poorly presented question. I think you're looking for:

```
DT[, VisitSources := PVsource[1], by = rleid(VisitID)]
```

Comment: why pourly? 
that is all code that i have. which take hours.i just want to change it to be faster.